# initialize in backbonejs

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am very new backbonejs, trying to play around with it. I put an alert message in initialize function but is not working.

```
$(function() {

    var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            alert("welcome to Backbone Application");
        }
    });

    var task = new Todo;

});
```

Complete code is available here http://jsfiddle.net/ZYxEw/

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The code is okay. You fiddle is just missing jQuery, UnderscoreJS.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYxEw/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is you included wrong javascript library path. Your fiddle is using relative path, change your src to something like: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js", "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" and "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" respectively.

If just for testing, you can add these libraries on the left panel of jsFiddle("Choose Framework" and/or "Add Resources" section).

Comment: also, I would suggest him to use properly Model View structure, even for trying this as a TEST.

Make a Model.
Create a view, call the Model.

And then initiate the same with a VIEW, but not with a model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

var task = new Todo();

Because it is a instance of a function you are calling

**EDIT**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYxEw/3/) `is a working fiddle for you`

Comment: `var task = new Todo` works just fine. However, it is probably not the best thing to do.